# Express Routes serving up as expected on local machine. But not when on Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, routes

Routes serving up as expected on my local machine. But not serving up /public or /api routes.

I've setup a serverblock for node.mydomain.com, installed a node app, and am getting 404 errors for all the routes express is supposed to be serving (static and api).

node.mydomain.com => /public/index.html (works fine)

node.mydomain.com/style.css => /public/style.css (404 error)

node.mydomain.com/api/puppies => /api (404 error)

This app should run in the root of my subdomain (node.mydomain.com) which is actually localhost:3000. What am I doing wrong?

NGINX SERVER BLOCKS

```
#server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/node.mydomain.com/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name node.mydomain.com www.node.mydomain.com;

location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            # node app hello.js
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location /app2 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

EXPRESS ROUTES

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist')));

app.use('/api', require('./api'));


// handle 404s
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

// handle 500s
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
console.error(err);
console.error(err.stack);
res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message || 'Internal server error.');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Your server, listening on port ${port}`);
    console.log(`Browse to http://localhost:${port} to view your app`);
});
```

API ROUTES

```
//api root
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
res.send('api root');
});

// /api/campuses
router.get('/campuses', function (req, res, next) {
Campuses.findAll({})
.then(campuses => res.json(campuses))
.catch(next);
});
```

Comment: You're getting 404 for all the routes in the api module, yet you don't show us that module.  We need to see that.  If the issue is in your Express code, then that's likely where it is.

Comment: It's for both the static and /api routes. But both work fine on my local machine. So I don't think it's route issue in my code or file structure. The static route is posted above. I will add the api routes though.

Comment: FYI: Figured this out it was in my nginx config file - had to remove one of the server directives.

Comment: Then you should either write an answer for your own question or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Nginx server block configuration issue. And nothing to do with the Express routes.

It depends on how the server blocks and your applications need to be setup. But in my case:

Removed the server directive for try_files. (Or move it down after the reverse proxy) depending on your needs.